# Python function inside a function

Tags: python, function, jupyter

I have some code down below. All of this was first done on Jupyter notebook and then I transferred into python file. I have a function that cleans text and when I apply:

```
df['First team_Players'] = df['First team_Players'].apply(clean_text)
```

the function will perform as it should. However when I create a function called all_nba_team() and try to run the clean_text function inside it, it doesn't seem to be performing this function. A little help would be appreciated :)

```
def clean_text(string):
    string = re.sub('\[.*?\]|[0-9*()^]', '', string)
    string = string.strip()

    return string
    

def all_nba_team():
   ...
   df['First team_Players'] = df['First team_Players'].apply(clean_text)
   ...

   return df
```

Here is an example of the output of the code:
[image]

And this is the output I am looking for:
[image]

Comment: What exactly happens? Can you provide sample inputs/outputs?

Comment: @ddcastrodd it would just print the dataframe without applying the clean_text function

Comment: can you provide sample df

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Did you try passing the DataFrame to `all_nba_team`? Did you assign the return value to domething?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def clean_text(string):
    string = re.sub('\[.*?\]|[0-9*()^]', '', string)
    string = string.strip()
    return string


def all_nba_team():
    data = {'players':  ['Pawan Singh* (2)', 'Magic johnson* (8)']}
    df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['players'])
    df['players'] = df['players'].apply(clean_text)

    return df

all_nba_team()
```

This seems to be working for me

See the working Example --

[image]

Comment: @angleofaxis Please accept the answer if its possible for you.